# RStudio - how to save global appearance settings

Tags: rstudio

**Is it possible to have my chosen global appearance/theme settings save in RStudio, so that it automatically applies the same settings/theme every time I open a new session?**

I have been having to manually go into global options and set my theme each time I log in, which is kind of annoying.

I haven't found any solid answers online thus far, so I'm wondering if this is possible, or if you just have to deal with setting it each time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could define your custom theme. To add a custom theme, navigate to the **Appearance Preferences Pane** in **Global Options** -> click the **Add** button and choose your [tmTheme](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/) file.

For more information: [https://www.rstudio.com/blog/rstudio-ide-custom-theme-support/#:~:text=Custom%20editor%20themes%20will%20allow,sharing%20an%20existing%20rstheme%20file](https://www.rstudio.com/blog/rstudio-ide-custom-theme-support/#:%7E:text=Custom%20editor%20themes%20will%20allow,sharing%20an%20existing%20rstheme%20file).